# Extracting last character from a string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pull the last word of a string, Example:

```
x='hello, what is your name?'
x=x[:-1] #to remove question mark 
lastword=findlastword(x)
print(lastword)
```

results : "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the text with punctuation and split (with whitespaces the default argument of `str.split()` method) then use a indexing to get the last word:

```
>>> import string
>>> x = 'hello, what is your name?'
>>> 
>>> x.strip(string.punctuation).split()[-1]
'name'
```

There is another way using regex which I don't recommend it for this task:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\b(\w+)\b\W$',x).group(1)
'name'
```